# How to print substring using RegEx in Python?

Tags: python, regex

This is two texts:

```
1) 'provider:sipoutilp1.ym.ms' 
2) 'provider:sipoutqtm.ym.ms'
```

I would like to print `ilp` when reaches to the fist line and `qtm` when reaches to the second line.

This is my solution but it is not working.

```
RE_PROVIDER = re.compile(r'(?P<provider>\((ilp+|qtm+)')
```

or in the line below,

```
182938,DOMINICAN REPUBLIC-MOBILE
```

to `DOMINICAN REPUBLIC` , can I use the same approach `re.compile`?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is not correct because you have a open parenthesis before your keywords, since there is no such character in your lines.

As a more general way you can get capture the alphabetical character after `sipout` or `provider:sipout`.

```
>>> s1 = 'provider:sipoutilp1.ym.ms'
>>> s2 = 'provider:sipoutqtm.ym.ms'
>>> RE_PROVIDER = re.compile(r'(?P<provider>(?<=sipout)(ilp|qtm))')
>>> RE_PROVIDER.search(s1).groupdict()
{'provider': 'ilp'}
>>> RE_PROVIDER.search(s2).groupdict()
{'provider': 'qtm'}
```

`(?<=sipout)` is a [positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which will makes the regex engine match the patter which is precede with `sipout`.

After edit:

If you want to match multiple strings with different structure, you have to use a optional preceding patterns for matching your keywords, and due to this point that you cannot use unfixed length patterns within look-behind you cannot use it for this aim. So instead you can use a capture group trick.

You can define the optional preceding patterns within a none capture group and your keyword within a capture group then after match get the second matched gorup (`group(1)`, `group(0)` is the whole of your match).

```
>>> RE_PROVIDER = re.compile(r'(?:sipout|\d+,)(?P<provider>(ilp|qtm|[A-Z\s]+))')
>>> RE_PROVIDER.search(s1).groupdict()
{'provider': 'ilp'}
>>> RE_PROVIDER.search(s2).groupdict()
{'provider': 'qtm'}
>>> s3 = "182938,DOMINICAN REPUBLIC-MOBILE"
>>> RE_PROVIDER.search(s3).groupdict()
{'provider': 'DOMINICAN REPUBLIC'}
```

*Note* that `gorupdict` doesn't works in this case because it will returns

Comment: thanks for your response, can u explain what are s1 and s2? I am trying to run it but it doesn't return me dictionary like {'pro...' : 'ilp'} and also I don't understand `(?<=sipout)` of reg edit.

Comment: @MaryamPashmi Welcome, They are your lines in separate variables.

Comment: I don't know why I am getting thsi error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'group'
` @Kasramvd

Comment: @MaryamPashmi It seems that you are trying to call a group on your dictionary result. Did you exactly run this code?

Comment: This is working in normal python editor. I am using it inside my python program. but don't worry I will try to find out it ;) @Kasramvd

Comment: @MaryamPashmi Maybe somewhere in your code you've passed the result of this regex to another method which attempts to call its `group` attr.

Comment: I 've edited my question. Is that possible to help me ?

Comment: Thank you for your help .. You have solved my problem perfectly;) @Kasramvd Good Luck

Comment: @MaryamPashmi Welcome, checkout the update with `groupdict` result.

Comment: to write it using positive look behind `RE_DESTINATION = re.compile(r'(?P<destination>)(?<=\,)(.*?)(<=\-)')` is not correct? considering it in separate sentences.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102589/discussion-between-maryam-pashmi-and-kasramvd).